# I got invalid_token although I use the correct token generated by authorizer server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Authorization Server using jdbc token store

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Bean
public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore(){
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
}

@Bean
protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices(){
    return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource))
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {        
    oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource);
}
```

Resource Server

```
private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "test";

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    }
}
```

ResourceController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transaction", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)


    public Map<String, Object> haloApi(@RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, String> input){Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("kwame", new Date());
    if(input != null){
        String name = input.get("test");
        if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()){
            data.put("nice", "Hello "+name);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

When I send a post request via cURL to Authorizer Server, I got a token in return but unfortunately when I use it in the Resource server it always return 
`invalid token` as response.

What am I missing?

See below my sample request for both *Authorizer* and *Resource Server* and advise please.

Authorizer Server:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -u "daniel:123456" "http://localhost:5600/oauth/token"
```

Sample response:

```
{
    "access_token": "cddc1b75-87d9-4a2f-9d66-210eae85b0f9",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 149,
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

When I use the token immediately as seen in the snippet below,

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5700/checkout/transaction -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer ac72b34f-437d-4134-8760-16f1ca3f0483' -d '{"test": "test"}'
```

I constantly get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "ac72b34f-437d-4134-8760-16f1ca3f0483"
}
```

Below is my log:

```
2017-01-08 18:45:36.375 DEBUG 11012 --- [io-22000-exec-1] o.s.s.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate   : GET request for "ip&port/oauth/check_token" resulted in 401 (null); invoking error handler
```

Here, my `application.properties` for resource server:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=5700
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=localhost:5600/oauth/check_token
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all...i finally discovered the issue!

Inside the application.properties i introduced

**security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:5600/oauth/check_token**

so I simply had to remove that line to fix the issue.

Special thanks to Cleto for your attention and contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using quotes before and after your token, please do the request without quotes `-H "Authorization: Bearer ac72b34f-437d-4134-8760-16f1ca3f0483"`

And please be sure that your token is still valid at the request time. ( see access_token_validity column on oauth_client_details table)

Edit:

I created a blank project with exactly the SAME authorization and resource server as yours, And I was able to make the request using:

> curl -X POST localhost:****/transaction -v -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   4c7591de-a4bc-4896-afc4-ed1fb7199c06" -d "{\"test\": \"test\"}"

Please use just double quotes on every parameter ( -H, -d ) and escape the double quotes of your data with .

When I was testing, I realized that you didn't set the resource_id of your resources:

```
resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
```

After set the ID, be sure that your database has a correct oauth_client_details with access to the resource.

If you check that everything looks OK but it's not working, please debug into spring API and see exactly the error.

Comment: Thanks Cleto but taking off the quotes resulted in this response **{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}** 

i.e; doing curl -X POST http://localhost:5700/checkout/transaction -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H Authorization: Bearer ec27410a-6135-4479-8fce-f2ca9de75831 -d '{"test": "test"}'

Comment: now your forgot the quotes on Header, please do -H "Authorization: Bearer ec27410a-6135-4479-8fce-f2ca9de75831"

Comment: _same response:_  **curl -X POST http://localhost:5700/checkout/transaction -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer e14bf836-bc8f-4b95-800d-d8ae630084ee" -d '{"test": "test"}'**

_Response_  **{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"e14bf836-bc8f-4b95-800d-d8ae630084ee"}**

_Any more advise_

Comment: i have updated the resource class above to include the resource ID per your advised, unfortunately issue persist.

Kindly see an update above of my application.properties , more specifically **security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri** if it's in order.

Comment: That's great! I didn't notice that 'check_token' endpoint. But I'm glad you did it.